# Can't understand why numpy's count_nonzero() seems not to be applicable to an ndarray

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to use numpy's `count_nonzero()`, but I keep getting an error message.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.full( (3, 3), 1, dtype='int')
print(arr.sum())                  # Produces 9 as expected
print(arr.count_nonzero(arr==1))  # Generates an error message

9
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count_nonzero'
```

This seems so simple, I can't understand what I'm missing. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In the numpy docs, functions appear as `numpy.count_nonzero`, while methods are `ndarray.squeeze`..  Some have both forms, others don't.  When you have problems like this check the docs.  Don't 'keep trying' things that produce errors.

Comment: Sorry. Must have been very tired when I wrote this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count_nonzero should be used like this

```py
print(np.count_nonzero(arr))
```